# Any tips to improve MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with 500K rows that looks like this: http://d.pr/njFJ

[image]

A query like this sometimes often takes more than 2 seconds:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `alerts` 
WHERE `a_timestamp` > '2012-04-15' AND `a_timestamp` <= '2012-04-16'  
   AND a_company_id IN(64,65,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,83,86,106,108,109,116,148) ORDER BY a_id DESC
```

Here's the explain query: http://d.pr/z20b

[image]

Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm missing something. Should it take that much time on such a small table?

Comment: @ Joel:) Where are they? Images are clear.

Comment: Did you try to reverse order of columns in index? Ie. a_company_id, a_timestamp?

Comment: Weird, images show OK for me. Edited to show external links instead.
@NikolaMarkovinović - yep, did not improve anything from what I could see.

Answer (score 2):

As KingFisher mentioned get rid of the `IN` clause (which is usually the bottleneck in query performance) and replace it with a `JOIN`, but don't use a temporary table, this is how you do it:

```
SELECT alerts.* FROM (
    (SELECT 64 AS id) UNION (SELECT 65) UNION (SELECT 69) UNION (SELECT 70)
    UNION (SELECT 71) UNION (SELECT 72) UNION (SELECT 73) UNION ...
) AS ids
INNER JOIN alerts ON (ids.id = alerts.a_company_id)
WHERE alerts.a_timestamp > '2012-04-15' AND alerts.a_timestamp <= '2012-04-16'
ORDER BY ids.id DESC
```

and make sure you have an index on `a_company_id`.

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Separate index on timestamp and separate on a_company_id?

Comment: For this query only the index on `a_company_id` would be important I don't think MySql use your index on `a_timestamp` here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to eliminate `IN` clause. It scans whole table for each value in 
`IN clause` that results in performance decrease.

You can use temp table for storing id's and use JOIN with id's in temp table instead of using `in` clause,

Comment: Hmmmm. Is it a problem with all INs or just in my particular case? I can just remove company_id condition and filter it with PHP in this case - there's not too many of them really. Also it's interesting that EXPLAIN query shows only 1087 rows...

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index on (a_company_id, a_timestamp)... the reverse order of the type_ts_company index.

Comment: The ultimate issue is that the range query on the timestamp is not able to use the index as range queries don't optimise well. Reversing the index allows the company_id IN to restrict the values that the range query will have to look at - as it will only have to inspect the values within the list of company id's, rather than all values in the table.

Comment: Range queries can definitely use an index.  It is just not very efficient if the range column is not the last one in the index key.  If there are thousands of company_ids in this database, with the range column first in the index, mysql will have to filter through thousands of company_ids that don't match.  But, if company_id is first, it can go through a range search for each individual company_id.  And doing that for a dozen or so is better than filtering out thousands of records that don't match.